# How to echo multiple images into the same div

Tags: php, html, image, foreach, echo

I am trying to make a site which will echo all the images in a directory to the page but when I am echoing them it creates a separate div for each.

```
  foreach($images as $img) {
  echo "<div class=\"container\"><img class=\"photo\" src=\"{$img['file']}\" {$img['size'][3]} alt=\"\">\n</div>";
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the `<div>` around your `foreach()` loop:

```
echo '<div class="container">';
foreach($images as $img) {
  echo "<img class=\"photo\" src=\"{$img['file']}\" {$img['size'][3]} alt=\"\">";
  }
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: this qusten have "\n" so you need to pass "<be>" tag or "\n"

Comment: @MHFuad "\n" doesn't do anything (visually) in HTML, in the source, yes, on the page, no. And, there is no <be> tag.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this solution, maybe it can help to you:

```
echo "<div class='container'>";
foreach ($images as $img) {
    echo "<img class='photo' src='{$img['file']}' {$img['size'][3]} alt=''>\n</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put div outside the foreach

```
echo "<div class=\"container\">"; 
foreach($images as $img) {
  echo "<img class=\"photo\" src=\"{$img['file']}\" {$img['size'][3]} alt=\"\">";
 }
echo "</div>";
```

With your actual code you create a `<div>` every loop

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you doing everything in the PHP side, but avoid HTML in PHP as much as you can, due to it being dirty coding.

I would:
1. Set the images into a variable;
2. Send the variable to the html template;
3. Loop it in the template where html is predominant;

If you absolutely have to do HTML in PHP, then I would go for a sprintf approach;

```
echo '<div class="container">';
foreach ($images as $img) {
    echo sprintf(
        '<img src="%s" class="img-rounded" alt="%s">',
        $img['file'],
        $img['filename']
    );
}
echo '</div>';
```

I find it clearer this way